# float div without width

Tags: css, css-float

I have 2 divs with text inside. I need to float the upper one to the right only, so that the second div with set width, shows along the first div. Is that possible? I can not figure this out. I do not want to set width of first div because I need it to wrap around second div.Thank you.

```
<div class="block1"></div>
<div class="block2"></div>

.block1 {float:right}
.block1 {border:2px solid green}
.block2 {border:2px solid red;
width:200px}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u2kCZ/1/

Comment: A div is a block level element and without a width will take up the full width of its parent element.

Comment: @j08691 so how to make it wrap around second div?

Comment: I suppose one way would be to instead float your second div to the left since it has a width. The only other change you'd need to make is to put the block2 div before the block1 div in your code like http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/u2kCZ/9/

Comment: yes I know about this, I was interested in the exact situation. So the result is that it can not be done with the html and css I provided. Thank you.

Comment: So? No acceptable answer so far? Did you fixed your issue?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to get your `<div class="block2">` inside `<div class="block1">`

http://jsfiddle.net/u2kCZ/10/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show `block1` next to `block2` on the right, just add a `float:right` to block2.